# Dynamically creating and reading global variables

Tags: angular, global-variables

In my angular app, I'm using a framework to render html dynamically. I will call the below method to render the html

```
Presto.layout(layoutJson, contentJson , document.getElementById('contentArea'), this.callbackFunction);
```

This will fetch the `contentJson` and build the html as per the `layoutJson` and inject into the `contentArea` div. 
Once the rendering is complete, the `callbackFunction` will be triggered.

**Issue**

```
public callbackFunction(callbackID) { 
   this.anotherFunction(); // This will not work as the `this` is replaced with another object.
}
```

None of the functions in the component is available inside the call-back function. The `this` object inside the callback function contains data associated with the `Presto js`. Can I save the old `this` globally and get it inside the callback function.

Comment: have you tried with binding? like `Presto.layout(layoutJson, contentJson , document.getElementById('contentArea'), this.callbackFunction.bind(this));`

Comment: Great.. that worked.. :) Post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the "binding" is missing in the callBack function, so try this:

`Presto.layout(layoutJson, contentJson , document.getElementById('contentArea'), this.callbackFunction.bind(this));`